# Xubuntu for programming and some gaming

Tags: xubuntu, python, games

Hello i'm wanted to ask you a question : is xubuntu are good in python programming and some gaming ? Because i wanted to get machine that will be good for learning python and to some light gaming.

Comment: Xubuntu is just a [*flavor*](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) of the Ubuntu Desktop system, created by a different *seed* file meaning different packages are included by default for a Ubuntu system.  Your question however would be better suited for a forum and not a Q&A site like this one (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) as there is no problem (*the question*) to be solved (ie. *what is answered*).  Your question is asking for off-topic *opinions* which is where forums work best (not Q&A sites like this)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Comment: The difference between ubuntu flavors and distros in general comes down to personal preference. Just google if the games you like can work or Linux or not.

Comment: Xubuntu is an official flavor (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) thus is built by launchpad from Ubuntu repositories thus from the same source as Ubuntu or all other flavors, just use a different and unique [Xubuntu seed](https://ubuntu-archive-team.ubuntu.com/seeds/xubuntu.lunar/desktop) meaning different installed defaults/packages are included on the Ubuntu base system. All releases can *differ* slightly, I used a 23.04 *seed* link as example so experiences can differ based on user's decisions (installation media, Xubuntu like Lubuntu.. vary GA/HWE kernel stack on media used etc)

Answer (score 0):

xubuntu is not any good in Python programming. It is the developer that can be good or not good.

xubuntu is a version of Ubuntu with the XFCE desktop, as opposed to the Gnome Shell desktop in the regular version of Ubuntu. The actual desktop environment does not make a fundamental difference in how good a platform (here GNU/Linux) is for a certain task.

Linux, so by extension Xubuntu, is the platform by excellence for developping, and preferred by many developpers, to the extent that developpers also use the Ubuntu based Windows Subsystem for Linux on MS Windows.

Linux is a less favored platform for games. Game developpers target the most widely used platforms first. Still, significant progress was made in more recent years, not in the least because Steam also became available on Ubuntu. For light gaming, you will be good. Again, it will not matter whether you use Xubuntu or another Ubuntu flavor.